# Problema al devolver un double en java Eclipse

Tags: java, scanner

Lo que me sucede es lo siguiente, al tratar de resolver la conversión de una unidad a otra con decimales, ingresando las variables por consola con la clase scanner  por ejemplo, al tratar de convertir 45.6 byte a bit  me presenta  error que esta al final,

```
import java.util.*;

public class Almacenamiento_cambio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double bit1=8;
        final double kilobyte=1024;// un kilobyte es igual a 1024 byte//

        Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("seleccione la unidad que desea convertir.");
    
        System.out.println("#1. De bit a byte");
    
        System.out.println("#2. De byte a bit");
    
        System.out.println("#3. De byte a kilobyte");
    
        System.out.println("#4. De kilobyte a byte");
    
        double  seleccion=entrada.nextDouble();
    }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at Almacenamiento_cambio.main(Almacenamiento_cambi
```

Comment: Parece mas bien que lo que intentas hacer es un menú, para luego según la opción indicada recibir un tipo de dato y convertirlo a otro, si es como pienso que es entonces te falta agregar la parte donde se hace la conversión. De ser asi como tu quieres asegurate de ingresar el numero usando como indicador decimal el punto .  y no la coma ,     Por eso te lanza la excepción InputMismatchException

Comment: El problema es simplemente que no estas introduciendo el valor correcto que debe ser Double al usar la función nextDouble()

Answer (score 1):

exacto, es lo que te dice darioxlz, ese error sucede cuando ingresas un tipo de dato distinto a lo que espera la funcion, puedes evitarlo usando un try cath o asegurandote el simbolo de coma

Answer (score 0):

Para entender lo que sucede revisa la documentación de la función nextDouble()

> [nextDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) Devuelve el siguiente token como doble. Si el siguiente
> token no es Double o está fuera de rango, se lanza
> `InputMismatchException`.

por lo tanto es un comportamiento normal ya que en este caso es necesario ingresar correcto, por ejemplo si ingresas un valor tipo String obtendrá el error `InputMismatchException` asegura que ingreses el valor double o flotante y además puedes validar con un manejo de excepciones

```
try {
    ...
    ...
    //Codigo!
    ...
    ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage()); 
}
```